# getting error while reading data from amazon redshift using spark(py)The bucket name parameter must be specified when requesting a bucket's location

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-redshift, apache-spark-sql

Can you help me with spark+redshift+data bricks driver, reading data.

for now iam getting error calling read method. below is my piece of code.

```
df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.redshift")
    .option("url",redshifturl).option("dbtable", "PG_TABLE_DEF")
    .option("tempdir","s3n://KEY_ID:SECRET_KEY_ID@/S2_BUCKET_NAME/TEMP_FOLDER_UNDER_S3_BUCKET/")
    .option("aws_iam_role","AWS_IAM_ROLE").load()
```

Below is error log i am getting

```
    IllegalArgumentException: u"The bucket name parameter must be specified when requesting a bucket's location"
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IllegalArgumentException                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-3255625043609925> in <module>()
----> 1 df = spark.read   .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift")   .option("url", redshifturl)   .option("dbtable", "pg_table_def")   .option("tempdir", "s3n://AKIAJXVW3IESJSQUTCUA:kLHR85WfcieNrd7B7Rm/1FK1JU4NeKTrpe8BkLbx@/weatherpattern/temp/")   .option("aws_iam_role", "arn:aws:iam::190137980335:user/user1")  .load()

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in load(self, path, format, schema, **options)
    163             return self._df(self._jreader.load(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
    164         else:
--> 165             return self._df(self._jreader.load())
    166 
    167     @since(1.4)

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1134 
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     77                 raise QueryExecutionException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
     78             if s.startswith('java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: '):
---> 79                 raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
     80             raise
     81     return deco

IllegalArgumentException: u"The bucket name parameter must be specified when requesting a bucket's location"
```

I think there is some problem with s3n path but way i have given in .option method looks correct with my real credentials.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks

### Imran :)

--

Answer (score 0):

Your path url is incorrect,

Format should be,

> s3n://ACCESSKEY:SECRETKEY@bucket/path/to/temp/dir

```
df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.redshift")
    .option("url",redshifturl).option("dbtable", "PG_TABLE_DEF")
    .option("tempdir","s3n://KEY_ID:SECRET_KEY_ID@S2_BUCKET_NAME/TEMP_FOLDER_UNDER_S3_BUCKET/")
    .option("aws_iam_role","AWS_IAM_ROLE").load()
```

**Documentation:**

https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Kannaiyan, I tried below this like you have said, but it now shows different error df = spark.read \
  .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift") \
  .option("url", redshifturl) \
  .option("dbtable", "pg_table_def") \
  .option("tempdir", "s3n://path/for/temp/data")\
  .option("aws_iam_role", iamrole)\
  .load()

Comment: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1684.load. : java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: I think it resolved the issue that the question is about. You have further errors now.